# What do we call a person who takes care of the child all the time?

Tags: single-word-requests

Please explain about that And I need one word of that.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/390066/a-better-word-than-babysitter-for-an-adult/390075#390075

Answer (score 0):

'Caregiver'. A (primary) caregiver is the person who takes primary responsibility for someone who cannot care fully for himself or herself, such as a child. However, the term is more often used for people looking after the old or infirm.

[[Caregiver - Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caregiver)

Answer (score -1):

**My answer:**

babysitter [Countable]

nanny [Countable]

**Why I recommend these words:**

The word "babysitter" is used to call a person that takes of children or babies temporarily.

The word "nanny" is used to call a person that takes of children or babies for a long period of time; let's say maybe 40 hours per week.

Comment: A babysitter is usually a short term role (i.e. for a few hours a week) so it's not a word applied to someone "who takes care of the child all the time".

Comment: Sounds fair. It's "nanny" then.